# Getting max value from a list in SML

Tags: list, recursion, sml

I'm currently studying SML and I'm having a hard time understanding the code below

```
fun good_max (xs : int list) =
  if null xs
  then 0
  else if null (tl xs)
  then hd xs
  else
    (* for style, could also use a let-binding for (hd xs) *)
    let val tl_ans = good_max(tl xs)
    in
      if hd xs > tl_ans
      then hd xs
      else tl_ans
    end
```

`hd xs` is of type `int` and `tl_ans`, I think is of type `list`.
Why does this code work? How does the system evaluate the recursion? 
It would be great if you could use `xs = [3, 4, 5]` to show me how this works.

Comment: `     let val y = old_max(tl[3,4,5])
     in
  max(hd[3,4,5], y)
     end

     let val y = (let val y' = old_max(tl(tl[3,4,5)))
   in
   max(hd(tl[3,4,5],y'))
      end)
     in max(hd[3,4,5],y)

     let val y = (let val y' = old_max([5]) in max(4,y') end) in max(3,y)
            end
     let val y = 5 in max (3,y)
     5`

Comment: ok. I mess up in trying to put code in the comment box. Thanks Andreas! I was able to figure out how yours work and applied it to my code. Using a helper function made the code more elegant :) My mistake in my assumptions happened because I didn't substitute all of the branches before I evaluated the function. Recursion is really a challenging topic.

Comment: FWIW, the `max` function already exists in the standard library as `Int.max`. Also, the right-hand side of the third case could obviously be simplified to just `max(x, goodMax xs)` -- I didn't do that to demonstrate how reduction inside a `let` works. Finally, I would suggest rather throwing an exception in the empty case, since 0 is not quite right as a result. Altogether, you can then express the function with a fold as simply `fun goodMax [] = raise Empty | goodMax(x::xs) = List.foldl Int.max x xs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me first rewrite this code to an equivalent but more readable version:

```
fun max(x,y) = if x > y then x else y

fun goodMax(nil) = 0
  | goodMax(x::nil) = x
  | goodMax(x::xs) = let val y = goodMax(xs) in max(x,y) end
```

Now we can consider how evaluation of `goodMax([3,4,5])` proceeds: conceptually, it will be *reduced* to an answer by repeatedly substituting the respective branch of the function definition(s):

```
  goodMax([3,4,5])
= goodMax(3::[4,5])
= let val y = goodMax([4,5]) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = goodMax(4::[5]) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = (let val y' = goodMax([5]) in max(4, y') end) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = (let val y' = goodMax(5::nil) in max(4, y') end) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = (let val y' = 5 in max(4, y') end) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = max(4, 5) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = (if 4 > 5 then 4 else 5) in max(3, y) end
= let val y = 5 in max(3, y) end
= max(3, 5)
= if 3 > 5 then 3 else 5
= 5
```

I have renamed the `y` in the inner invocation to `y'` for clarity.

Comment: `     let val y = old_max(tl[3,4,5])
     in
  max(hd[3,4,5], y)
     end

     let val y = (let val y' = old_max(tl(tl[3,4,5)))
   in
   max(hd(tl[3,4,5],y'))
      end)
     in max(hd[3,4,5],y)

     let val y = (let val y' = old_max([5]) in max(4,y') end) in max(3,y)
            end
     let val y = 5 in max (3,y)
     5`