# What are the advantages of using Options for getting the Max of a list of integers in SML

Tags: sml

In my previous question yesterday [Getting max value from a list in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823378/getting-max-value-from-a-list-in-sml/20823652#20823652), I figured out with the help of Andreas Rossberg how to evaluate a function that gets the Max of a list of integers using SML.

Continuing on to my study. The same code was revised to use Options. Here is the code

```
fun max1 (xs : int list) =
  if null xs
  then NONE
  else 
    let val tl_ans = max1(tl xs)
    in
      if isSome tl_ans andalso valOf tl_ans > hd xs
      then tl_ans
      else SOME (hd xs)
    end
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why does the code inside the else statement output a value of type `option`?
2. What are the advantages of using `option`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A comment on your first question: not only the else-branch results in a value of type `option`, this is also true for the if-branch (i.e., `NONE`). In general both branches of an if-construct have to have the same type.

As for your second question. The `option` type is often used to explicitly encode partiality of a function (i.e., if there is no proper *result* for input). In the case of getting the maximum value contained in a list this happens when the input is the empty list. With the function from you previous post we get

```
max [] = 0
```

(in words: *the maximum value contained in the empty list is 0*), which is somehow wrong since we would for example also get

```
max [0] = 0
```

To distinguish these two cases we can use the `option` type, resulting in

```
max1 [] = NONE
max1 [0] = SOME 0
```

The reason for returning an option type, in this case an `'int option`, is that we get more fine-grained information: firstly, already the type of `max1`, i.e., `int list => int option`, tells us that the function is partial (we might either get `SOME` result or `NONE`); secondly, whenever we get `NONE` we know that the input was the empty list.